# How to remove Field Name in custom message in class-validator NestJS

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I have problems with regards to creating custom messages using the `class-validator`. It always returns the field name.

```
export class EditOrderAddressDto implements Partial<CreateOrderAddressDto> {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(1, { message: 'Last Name should at least have more than 1 character.'})
  lastName?: string;
}

export class EditOrderDto implements EditOrderDtoModel {
  @ApiProperty({ required: false })
  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => EditOrderAddressDto)
  billingAddress?: Partial<CreateOrderAddressDto>;
 }
```

Then for my payload I just pass this.

```
{ deliveryAddress:
 { lastName: "" } 
}
```

And I get this as the error message  "deliveryAddress.Last Name should at least have more than 1 character.'

Is there any way I can remove the `deliveryAddress` and return only the custom message?